# Displaying a MySQL table

Tags: mysql-cli

I made a request on MySQL. The table is not displayed correctly. Can you help me? Thank you[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9Bl4.jpg). My database is with 4 tables.

I want a solution for the correct display of the table. Thank you :)

Comment: Please do not add random tags to your question. This is a display issue in mysql's command line client, it does not have anything to do with excel, sql, mysql, or window.